# is there a way to automate giving permission to google auth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

we are trying to use google spreadsheets api using oauth2.0 authentication. we used the following code from google api documentation for oauth authentication

```
def get_credentials():
        CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
        SCOPES=[
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
        ]
        APPLICATION_NAME = 'Knab'
        home_dir=os.path.expanduser('~')
        credential_dir=os.path.join(home_dir,'.credentials')
        if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
            os.makedirs(credentials_dir)
        credential_path=os.path.join(credential_dir,'knab.json')
        store=oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
        credentials=store.get()
        if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
            flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,SCOPES)
            flow.user_agent=APPLICATION_NAME
            if flags:
                credentials=tools.run_flow(flow,store,flags)
            else:
                credentials=tools.run(flow,store)
        return credentials;

    credentials=get_credentials()
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    discoveryUrl = ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
                        'version=v4')
    service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http,
                                  discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)
```

I have created oauth2 key and passing the json file (client_secret.json), everything works well, but when we run the code on a fresh
machine, it asking us to open a google link and login with credentials and click on allow. We are about to put in amazon lambda as
microservice. So, there shouldn't be manual intervention. I have tried to run with --noauth_local_webserver as command-line argument.
It's asking to visit the url and enter the code. My idea is to SSH a different machine, run a selenium code to open the url and login with
my google credentials, allow permissison and return the code back to the program. I got a idea, but don't know how to implement it,
any suggestions welcome please....

Comment: I suggest sticking with what's stated on the Google docs [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python). I'm sure Google has its reasons for setting it that way, primarily for security purposes. This is to avoid pre-programmed robotic or automating behavior.